# В чем различия между const и final?

Tags: dart, const, final

```
//Почему мы можем сделать так:
var list = const [1,2,3];
//Но не можем так:
var list2 = final [1,2,3];
```

Почему final нельзя ставить справа от знака равенства, а const можно? Ведь их смысл практически одинаковый.

Comment: а) Предложенный ответ вам не помог? б) Исправте сам текст вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в dart ключевые слова `const` и `final` имеют разное назначение, хоть и есть схожие моменты.

Ключевое слово `final` используется для того, чтобы указать, что переменная не может быть перезаписана, но это не значит, что сам объект не может быть изменяемым. `const` же позволяет нам создавать неизменяемые (immutable) объекты, то есть мы не можем изменять поля `const` экземляра. К примеру:

```
final finalList = [1, 2, 3];
const constList = [1, 2, 3];

finalList.add(4);
print(finalList); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
constList.add(4); // Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: add
```

В данном примере переменная `constList` является неизменяемым так же, как и его объект `[1, 2, 3]`. То есть мы можем переписать вторую строку как `const constList = const [1, 2, 3];` и смысл не поменяется.

Comment: Выяснил также, что ключевое слово const предназначено для объявления конструкторов, которые создают постоянные значения.

Comment: И отсюда следующий вопрос: если     var list = const [1,2,3]; -это объявление константного конструктора для создания обьекта класса List, то почему в классе List в документации нет константного конструктора? Как вобще понять, что у класса может быть константный конструктор?

Comment: @neyrodzen все правильно, для того, чтобы узнать возможность создать константный объект, достаточно посмотреть, имеет ли конструктор ключевое слово `const`. В случае с `var list = const [1, 2, 3];` объект создается с помощью встроенного в dart литерала списка - `[1, 2, 3]`.  Просто нужно запомнить: литералы коллекций `<Object>[]` - List, `<Object>{}` - Set, `<Object, Object>{}` - Map позволяют добавлять префикс `const`

Comment: Спасибо за ваше объяснение, еще вопрос по этой теме. Почему когда мы пишем const constList = [1, 2, 3]; а затем пытаемся изменить поле constList.add(4); то VS Code выдает ошибку только после запуска, а не видит ее сразу? Мое предположение, что это потому что литерал листа это тоже объект, и под капотом он возвращает ссылку на ячейку памяти, поэтому переменная constList не проинициализирована пока программа не запустится. То есть constList в итоге хранит ссылку или значения?